# React with typescript ==>No overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting below error in the screeshot error_2[image]
Here AgGridReact is imported from the ag-grid-react library which i have imported at the top of my code .So i want ask to how can I declare interface to the AgGridReact because it not the component .If it will be normal component then It will be easy to just declare the interface and declare the props inside it

Below is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AgGridColumn, AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import './Grid.scss';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

type MyProps = {
    className:any
    rowData:any
    columns:any
    updateRecord:any
    onDeleteRecord:any
    noHoverEffect:any 
    gridOptions:any
    onRowEditingStopped:any
};

type MyState = {
};

export default class Grid extends Component<MyProps, MyState> {
    constructor(props:MyProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }


    onCellClicked = (params:any) => 
    {
        // Handle click event for action cells
        if (params.column.colId === "Action" && params.event.target.dataset.action) 
        {
            let action = params.event.target.dataset.action;

            if (action === "update") 
            {
                this.props.updateRecord(params.node.data.id, params.node.data.name, params.node.data.description, params.node.data.created, params.node.data.created_By);
            }

            if (action === "delete") {
                this.props.onDeleteRecord(params.node.data)

            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        const gridOptions = {
            getRowStyle: (params:any) => {
                if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 1) {
                    return { background: '#ebebeb73' };
                }
            },
        };

        
        return (
            <div className={["sct-grid", this.props.className, this.props.noHoverEffect && "nohover"].filter(Boolean).join(" ")}>
                <AgGridReact gridOptions={gridOptions}
                    alignedGrid="true"
                    suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns={true}
                    pagination={true}
                    paginationPageSize={7}
                    rowData={this.getitems()}
                    onRowEditingStopped={this.onRowEditingStopped}
                    onRowEditingStarted={this.onRowEditingStarted}
                    onCellClicked={this.onCellClicked}
                    editType="fullRow"
                    suppressClickEdit={true}
                    enableRangeSelection={true}
                    columnDefs={this.props.columns}

                >

                    {/* { this.getColumns()}*/}

                </AgGridReact>
            </div>
        );
    }

    getitems() {
        return this.props.rowData;
    }



    getColumns() {
        var listOfColumns :any = [];
        if (this.props.columns) {
            this.props.columns.forEach((column:any) => {
                listOfColumns.push(<AgGridColumn key={column} minWidth="80" maxWidth="120" field={column.field} sortable={column.sortable} filter={column.filter}></AgGridColumn>);
            });
        }
        return listOfColumns;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Following [the documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-styles/#row-style), you either need to add `getRowStyle` property to the `AgGridReact` component, and/or always return styles from `getRowStyle` function in `gridOptions`. Because right now, if your condition `if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 1)` returns `false`, `getRowStyle` function is going to return `undefined`(which `AgGridReact` apparently doesn't like if looking at the error message).